# prinvt content of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

Resolved, thanks all. The vector needs to be initialized.

I am new in c++. I appreciate it if you cuold help me print the content of the following vector v. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    std::cout << "hello world\n";

    std::vector<int>* v;    (<-- std::vector<int>* v = new std::vector<int>();]
    v->push_back(17);
    v->push_back(12);
    v->push_back(23);
    v->push_back(42); 

    for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = v->begin(); it!= v->end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << "\n";
    }
    std::cout <<"done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `v` a pointer?

Comment: @Kevin, **invalid** pointer to be precise.

Comment: It is a pointer in another program that I need need to print out. the original one is vector<uint64_t> *

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Why is it a pointer to a vector instead of the vector itself?

Comment: @crownLearnig - if you **really** want use a pointer, you should allocate it with `new`

Comment: here is the function from the original code:  

void AddItem(uint64_t fkey, vector<uint64_t>* lFeatures) {
    lFeatures->push_back(fkey);
  }

Comment: @crownLearning: There's no reason for a function to take a pointer to a vector.

Comment: @crownLearning: "*It is a pointer in **another program** that I need need to print out*" - it is dangerous to access/manipulate another program's `vector` (or any other data, for that matter), especially if you don't know what STL implementation it is using. Even if you could access it, you can't use `iterator`s to access its content, as they will only be valid within the *other* program, not within *your* program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to allocate memory for your vector pointer. I'd rather recommend just using a variable allocated on the stack:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    std::cout << "hello world\n";

    std::vector<int> v; // <<<<< Note that * was omitted here
    v.push_back(17);
    v.push_back(12);
    v.push_back(23);
    v.push_back(42); 

    for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it!= v.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << "\n";
    }
    std::cout <<"done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

See the [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73e2cf6a08e5dcb9).

---

As for your edit:

> v will be used as follows:
>
> ```
>  void AddItem(uint64_t fkey, vector<uint64_t>* v) {
>       v->push_back(fkey);
>  }
> ```

Rather choose this signature:

```
void AddItem(uint64_t fkey, vector<uint64_t>& v) {
                                         // ^ << Choose a reference
   v.push_back(fkey);
 // ^ << dereference accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to make `v` a pointer here, use something like this instead:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>    

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v;
    // push_back data...

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,","));

}
```

This will print out the contents of `v` from beginning to end separated by `,` chars.

If you really want to make `v` a pointer to a `std::vector` though, then try the following:

```
int main() {

    std::vector<int>* v = new std::vector<int>(); // allocate memory on heap
    v->push_back(17);
    // etc...

    std::copy(v->begin(), v->end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,","));

    delete v; // make sure to delete from heap to prevent memory leak

}
```

Comment: `delete`? In 2016?

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury, well, do I really have to lecture you on memory management in C++ in 2016? There is no shortage of those materials in the web.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Ah well, granted, but assuming that the function signature the OP provided for `AddItem` is part of a library that they cannot change then a normal pointer is the only option here :)

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury, why is that?

Comment: @SergeyA Unless I'm mistaken one cannot pass something of type `std::unique_ptr<Type>` to a function with signature `func(Type*)`

Comment: You can certainly pass a pointer to a managed object (on the stack or in a smart pointer) to a function. The problem comes from using a raw pointer as the owner of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is not real code because there is no good reason to use a pointer to a vector in this case and the pointer doesn't point at anything.

But if your question is just how to print the contents of a vector given a pointer then you can simply dereference the pointer and use a range-based for loop.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void print(std::vector<int>* v) {
    for(int value : *v)
        std::cout << value << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
    std::vector<int> v = {17, 12, 23, 42};
    print(&v);
    std::cout <<"done\n";
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VI6TWl2hIQlrYeUJ).